# Check value above to identify the same value as one item

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
ID  Item       No of items    No of items ordered
1   Vauxhall   
2   Vauxhall                         40
3   Vauxhall       30                 
4   Vauxhall                         60
6   Vauxhall  
7   Vauxhall       40
8   Vauxhall                         25
9   Vauxhall       
10  BMW            30
11  BMW  
12  BMW            25
13  BMW            
14  BMW                              55
15  BMW  
16  BMW  
17  BMW            20
18  BMW
```

Each item has nine rows. I would like VBA code or a formula to look at the 'Item' above active cell and if the 'Item' is the same and the 'No of Items' field is blank, I would like it to copy the next available value in 'No of Items' to the cells above which are empty. If there is no next available 'No of Items' for one item then put default value of `100`.

I would like the result to look:

```
ID  Item       No of items    No of Items ordered
1   Vauxhall                          40
2   Vauxhall                          40
3   Vauxhall       30                   
4   Vauxhall                          60
6   Vauxhall       40
7   Vauxhall       40
8   Vauxhall                          25
9   Vauxhall      100 
10  BMW            30
11  BMW            25
12  BMW            25
13  BMW                               55
14  BMW                               55 
15  BMW            20
16  BMW            20
17  BMW            20
18  BMW           100
```

Comment: Best to describe specifically what you want to do and what you'd like the result to be.  Right now your question is too vague.

Comment: looks like a for next loop on the chars, so r=range("B" & loopcount) then if r.offset(-1,0).value<>r.value then...   Agree, its realy vague a question tho.

Comment: Is the dataset sorted? What the "else" and "something else" will be? Please include that info in your edit of the question, as it stand now it may get deleted...

Comment: I have tried the r=range("B" & loopcount) then if r.offset(-1,0).value<>r.value then, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If `ID` is in A1 then you might try in D2 copied down to suit:

```
=IF(B1=B2,"Do something","Do something else")
```

The general principle is the same for VBA (say If ... Else) but VBA has much more scope for what to do or what else to do.

---

**Concerning your edit** you'd need to adapt the above formula so it differentiates the last in each group, rather than the first, say in E2 copied down to suit:

```
=B2<>B3
```

Filter ColumnE to select TRUE and filter ColumnC to select (Blanks). Fill those with `100` and then fill ColumnC by selecting it, Go To Special..., Blanks (only), `=`,  Down, Ctrl+Enter ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27511788/1505120)).